# When is it acceptable to use the ViewData dictionary in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It seems like most people are leaning towards creating single ModelViews for each view ([Thunderdome Principle](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/10/23/our-opinions-on-the-asp-net-mvc-introducing-the-thunderdome-principle.aspx)) in lieu of stuffing in weakly typed items into the ViewData dictionary.

So, with this in mind, for what tasks should the ViewDictionary be used for then?  Really small one-off views?  Don't use it at all?

Comment: I recommend having a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/06/17/a-new-and-improved-asp-net-mvc-t4-template.aspx). You obviously can have everything strongly typed with minimal effort! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never, keep everything strongly typed.  Helps with refactoring, that enough is reason alone.

Answer (score 3):

MasterPages strike me as a place where it's tough to get around them.  Let's say you have a standard place on all your pages where error messages are going to be displayed.  You *could* theoretically strong type the MasterPage and make sure that all view models inherit from some base class that gives you strong-typed access to the variable for setting the error message in your master page, but that seems like overkill.  It's much more reasonable to do something like:

```
ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "This is an error message";
```

and have your master page have a section displaying it:

```
<div class="error_message"><%= ViewData["ErrorMessage"] %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is: *use strongly-typed Views on not and when?*. If your Views are not strongly-typed then you will be using ViewDataDictionary (mostly for simple/small apps). If you are using Unit Testing it is better to have View Model which can be simply tested.